# iOS app "missing 64-bit support" error during upload via application loader

Tags: ios, xcode6, arm, app-store

I was trying to submit my app via application loader, and this error came out :

> To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK

***I have updated Valid Architectures and Architectures section of Build Settings in target to include "arm64". Set Build Active Architecture Only - NO. Did clean and build***, and then these errors came out:

> *Apple mach-o linker error - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in EGCryptoProvider*

EGCryptoProvider is a library I'm using to handle ecryption/decryption of sign certificates. I assume this error means this library doesn't support arm64 architecture. *My question is*, **is there a workaround to this error, or is it possible to not include a support for arm64 architecture in my project in order to submit it to AppStore?**

Comment: Just like @Sanjay Mohnani has mentioned, your EGCryptoProvider binary doesn't support 64bit architecture. To make sure you can run lipo -info. Try to build a fat binary for your library (if possible). Here's a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: @SantuC it's totally different than that question you have mentioned. I know the reason for my problem, I'm not asking why this happened. My question is, is there a way to workaround this error, or to not include a support for arm64 architecture in my project in order to submit it to AppStore?

Comment: @FlySoFast you are absolutely right, a fat binary for EGCryptoProvider with arm64 architecture is required to be created, but it will only be possible if source code for the EGCryptoProvider is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Apple mach-o linker error - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in EGCryptoProvider
```

As the above error suggests '`EGCryptoProvider` is missing architecture `arm64`', since it's not build for that architecture.

You should use the latest version of `EGCryptoProvider`, check if it's having the support for `arm64 architecture`.

If it doesn't support arm64 architecture than the only thing you can do is add architecture arm64 in `EGCryptoProvider` and recreate the static library using `lipo command`, re integrate it in your project. But you can only do so if you have the source for the same, otherwise you should contact the developer of the `EGCryptoProvider` to provide the library with the support for arm64 architecture.